# Jest test returns "ReferenceError: tsx is not defined" in React/TypeScript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm attempting to write Jest tests in a React project where some of the TypeScript settings are being forced upon me.

In a minimalistic `test.tsx` (that sits in the `test` folder) I've got:

```
import React from 'react';

describe('Test', () => {
    test('Test', () => {
        let div = <div></div>;
        console.log(div);
    })
});
```

My error results in:

```
 ReferenceError: tsx is not defined

      3 | describe('Test', () => {
      4 |     test('Test', () => {
    > 5 |         let div = <div></div>;
        |                   ^
      6 |         console.log(div);
      7 |     })
      8 | });
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "tsx",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "reports",
        "test"
    ]
}
```

I'm required to have these lines:

```json
"jsx": "react",
"jsxFactory": "tsx",
```

Here is my `jest.config.json` file:

```json
{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "reporters": [
        "default",
        "jest-junit"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "reports",
    "coverageReporters": [
        "text",
        "cobertura"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "!**/node_modules/**",
        "!**/test/**",
        "!**/dist/**"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.ts[x]?$": [
            "ts-jest",
            {
                "isolatedModules": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "displayName": {
        "name": "Report",
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/dist"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(css)$": "<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/styles.js"
    }
}
```

Here are my relevant dependencies from `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.9.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "jest-junit": "16.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
```

I tried changing all the settings that I could tweak in both the `tsconfig.json` file and the `jest.config.json` files to no avail.

Comment: It's clearly `"jsxFactory": "tsx"` that's causing the problem, because `<div></div>` becomes something like `tsx("div", {}, [])`, so: forced by what or whom? What's providing that at runtime? What's replacing that in the tests?

Comment: The integration that we're doing forces the `jsxFactory` setting...which I'd love to remove.

Comment: What integration? You could potentially replace it in tests (either override the setting or provide an alternative global) but that might not give representative test results.

Answer (score 0):

To get past the particular error I needed to ensure that my test files were getting included in the `tsconfig.json`, in which I had the `test` folder excluded to avoid the tests being 'compiled' during a build.

I added a separate `tsconfig.json` file in my `test` folder like so:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": true
    }
}
```